# How to generate SEO friendly URL using Kohana

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, kohana

Currently my `url` looks like `mysite.com/product/display/10` means `domain/controller/function/id` for SEO friendly sake I'm thinking to append `product title` which will be like `product name something`.

With my basic knowledge on `SEO` what I know is,for `SEO` friendly my `url` should be like `mysite.com/product/display/product-name-something/id`

Is there any efficient way to do this in `Kohana 2.x` , if it is not possible with `Kohana`,please suggest a efficient and better way in `PHP` by using `.htaccess` file or without `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ROUTES, to declare friendly URL's. In file config/routes.php, like this:

```
$config['route'] = 'class/method';
```

in Your case:

```
$config['product/display/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)'] = 'product/display/$2';
```

More: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/routing

To change strings use this:

```
function toUrl($string) {
        // small fonts
        $sText = strtolower($string);
        // change spaces to -
        $sText = str_replace(' ', '-', $sText);
        // delete all other characters to -
        $sText = preg_replace('|[^0-9a-z\-\/+]|', '', $sText);
        // delete too much - if near
        $sText = preg_replace('/[\-]+/', '-', $sText);
        // trim -
        $sText = trim($sText, '-');

        return $sText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,here I need to convert `product title` which will be like `product name something` to `product-name-something` how can I do this efficiently.

Comment: Please suggest a regular expression pattern for second argument in this `$config['product/display/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)'] = 'product/display/$2` in such way that `it must be optional` and it will be a combination of words like `product-name-something`.

Comment: $config['product/display/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?'] = 'product/display/$2'; If something is optional just put it in (expression)?